# check is json key exists or not in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

im getting json data from one api 
my  respons is below and im putting it in notes variable.
    {"fitbit_reg_set":"fitbit_create_uname","fitbit_profile_set":"fitbit_create_uname"}

```
<#assign notes =  notes?eval>

<#if notes.fitbit_profile_set>
```

it works if fitbit_profile_set is present in json . but if that is not present my script stop working .How i can check if that is exists can anyone tell me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add "??" so it will check if fitbit_profile_set exists and not null

<#if notes.fitbit_profile_set??>

Comment: <assign key = "fitbit_profile_set">
<#if notes.key??>
my key is in variable can i do like this?